# jquery method doesn't fire after page loaded via ajax jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile and on my main page, have this code to show the login if needed:

```
 $.mobile.changePage( "login.html", { transition: "slideup"} );
```

In the login, I have a form and then this event which will fire, do some stuff then submit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login').submit(function() {
              alert('about to do stuff...');

            }); 

});
```

The problem is that never appears to bind to the login form if I load the page via ajax.  If I don't load via ajax, I lose the transition.  How can I get it to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to realize is, document.ready is not as relevant in the jquery mobile world.  document.ready is fired when the DOM is complete.  What you want is the events that fire around the page creation and page transitions of each "page."

The one that you want is: **[pageinit](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html)**.

```
//Triggered on the page being initialized, after initialization occurs. We recommend 
//binding to this event instead of DOM ready() because this will work regardless 
//of whether the page is loaded directly or if the content is pulled into another 
//page as part of the Ajax navigation system.


$( '#loginPage' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
  alert( 'This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!' );
});
```

If you wanted to, you could bind to the login form or any other piece of that "page" if you like.  You can also just hook into the form with a live.

This...

```
$('#login').submit(function() {
    alert('about to do stuff...');
});
```

becomes this...

```
$('#login').live('submit', function() {
    var $form = $(this);
    alert('about to do stuff...');
});
```

The only thing about this is that the more "live" events that you use, the more bogged down your application will become.  It causes a lot of event bubbling.

For the best performance, you should really just be using a named function and hook in using the onsubmit on the form tag itself.  I know it may not be fashionable but it is the fastest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with the jQuery Mobile framework, but if its like the jQuery framework you may want to try the `.live('submit', function(){....`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Jquery Mobile yet, but if you load the page via Ajax, binds don't work if page elements (like your form) are added to your DOM after the fact.  You can use [.live()](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/experiments/api-viewer/docs/live/index.html) to bind to your page form elements on the page already or in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you are struggling with query after Ajax call, there is an ajaxEvent for this particular task.

.ajaxComplete() Refer : http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

This is a more appropriate event than .ready() or .live() when you are working with Ajax.